Laggy Wayland with nvidia in Ubuntu 24.10
I used X11 up until Ubuntu 24.04 because Wayland had compatibility issues with my setup. However, due to some specific tasks and improved Wayland support for NVIDIA graphics in 24.10, I decided to switch to Wayland.
Wayland definitely boots faster and offers a smoother experience in applications like Nautilus. However, I’ve noticed some issues: pressing the Super/Win key on the main display causes choppy animations, even with no background apps running. Additionally, when connecting an external monitor via HDMI, I experience system-wide lag across GNOME, including while scrolling in Chrome or performing other tasks on the secondary monitor. Interestingly, everything runs smoothly on X11 without these problems.
My setup includes a Lenovo Legion laptop with an i7-10750H, 16GB RAM, and an RTX 2060 mobile GPU, running proprietary NVIDIA drivers version 560. Ubuntu is installed on an NVMe SSD.
Is there anything I can adjust to improve this performance, or is this simply a limitation I’ll have to accept with Wayland?

I have the same problem on my HP Zbook laptop, it is unusably slow even when typing and when moving the mouse you can feel the lag. I'm on an i9 with an RTX4500 which was fast in 24.04, but now no longer.
I found here that there is a bug in 6.11 kernel / nvidia 560 drivers that causes bad performance and /usr/bin/gnome-shell to consume a lot of CPU. I tried 550 and 535 drivers, no change. Tried 6.8 kernel but that also didn't solve the problem.
I found here that the 470 driver works, however that is End of Life and discontinued in 24.10.
So, the bug either gets fixed or we need to go back to 24.04.
(I also tried Nouveau but could not get my external monitor to work)

Well, I also had the same problem when I updated to 24.10, and I was kind of trying to find out where the problem was (driver, kernel, os version...), and if I remember well I solved it installing the 535 driver, leaving me to believe this was a problem within the nvidia drivers (560). But then I decided to roll back as I've learnt that this kernel version had a problem with coming back from sleep mode. I also have some recent specs: Aorus 15 9kf laptop, i5 12500h, RTX 4060 and 16gb ram.

I no longer use Nvidia, so this is from memory:
Wayland is notorious for not playing nicley with Nvidia. However, I seem to remember that installing libnvidia-egl-wayland1 worked for me. You might want to investigate that further.

it came preinstalled on ubuntu 24.10 so this might have helped me in 24.04, as for now this seems to a dead end

Ok, I did say that it was from memory. I'm afraid that as I no longer use Nvidia (as I mentioned), I can't help any further. Apologies, and good luck!
